# Loss function doesn't have requires_grad=True in pytorch

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, gradient, loss-function

Hello I have the following code (simplified version of my code but able to reproduce the error):

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import linalg as LA
import torch
import torch.optim as optim 
import torch.nn as nn

def func(x,pars):
    a = pars[0]
    b = pars[1]
    c = pars[2]
    d = pars[3]

    x = x.int()

    H = torch.tensor([[a,b,1],[2,3,c],[4,d,7]])

    eigenvalues, eigenvectors = np.linalg.eigh(H)

    trans_freq = eigenvalues[x]

    return torch.tensor(trans_freq)

x_index = torch.tensor([1,2])
y_vals = torch.tensor([0.5,12])

params = torch.tensor([1.,2.,3.,4.])
params.requires_grad=True
opt = optim.SGD([params], lr=100)

mse_loss = nn.MSELoss()

for i in range(10):
  opt.zero_grad()
  loss = mse_loss(func(x_index,params),y_vals)
  print(x_index.requires_grad)
  print(params.requires_grad)
  print(y_vals.requires_grad)
  print(loss.requires_grad)
  loss.backward()
  opt.step() 
  print(loss)
```

The output is:

```
False
True
False
False
```

and I am getting this error: `RuntimeError: element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn` from this line: `loss.backward()`. Indeed the loss doesn't have `requires_grad=True` but why is that the case (setting it manually in the for loop doesn't work either). What should I do? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a line `loss.requires_grad = True` before `loss.backward()`

```
for i in range(10):
  opt.zero_grad()
  loss = mse_loss(func(x_index,params),y_vals)
  print(x_index.requires_grad)
  print(params.requires_grad)
  print(y_vals.requires_grad)
  print(loss.requires_grad)

  loss.requires_grad = True     # Here you need to add this line
  loss.backward()
  opt.step() 
  print(loss)
```

Comment: That doesn't work. It doesn't throw the error anymore, but the loss doesn't change

Answer (score 0):

The parameters optimized should be `requires_grad`, then the loss is a func of parameters and is `requires_grad` automatically.

When you want to use the autograd, you could try to plot the relation graph.
There is a little example:

```py
import torch
import torch.optim as optim 
import torch.nn as nn

def func(x, w):
    return x @ w

x = torch.tensor([1.0,2])
y = torch.tensor([0.5,12])

w = torch.ones((2, 2), requires_grad=True)

opt = optim.SGD([w], lr=0.1)

mse_loss = nn.MSELoss()

for i in range(10):
    opt.zero_grad()
    y_hat = func(x, w)
#     print(y_hat.requires_grad)
    loss = mse_loss(y_hat,y_vals)
#     print(x.requires_grad)
#     print(w.requires_grad)
#     print(y_vals.requires_grad)
#     print(loss.requires_grad)
    loss.backward()
    opt.step() 
    print(loss)

print(x @ w)
```

Then you could write code gracefully.

Comment: But I thought requires_grad=True is only for variables I want to change during optimization. Also, shouldn't the indices be integers? Do I need to go back and forth between treating them as integers and floats?

Comment: Yes, `requires_grad=True` is only for variables I want to change during optimization. Only when one or more operands are requires_grad, the result will be requires_grad auto. You could change your `func` ```return torch.tensor(trans_freq, requires_grad=True)```, but this is not a good example.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. In my case the x_index and y_vals are the data, they shouldn't change, so why should I set requires_grad=True for them? I only want to optimize the params. When I train a normal machine learning algorithm, I only make the weights and biases have requires_grad=True (which would be params in this case), not the input and output.

Comment: I am wrong, should not set `requires_grad=True` for `x_index` and `y_vals`.

Comment: yeah... but in that case I am getting the error in the original post